# Invalid input source specified

Tags: solidity, remix

getting an Invalid input source specified error with the following import when building a smart contract using the remix IDE

```
import "https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/Remix/contracts/aave/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
```

Put together a super basic example smart contract in remix. It compiles just fine if I dont include the import statement.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.6;
import "https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/Remix/contracts/aave/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol";
contract Inbox {
    string public message; 
    
    constructor(string memory initialMessage) public {
        message = initialMessage;
    }
    
    function setMessage(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
    }
    
    function getMessage() public view returns (string memory) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is happening because of the nested import using relative path.

The `FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol` is trying to import relative path `./IFlashLoanReceiver.sol` (not absolute path `https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box/blob/Remix/contracts/aave/IFlashLoanReceiver.sol`).

Since you don't have a contract named `IFlashLoanReceiver.sol` in the same folder as your own contract, this import fails.

Best solution would be to submit a PR to the [aave/flashloan-box](https://github.com/aave/flashloan-box) repository making all import paths absolute.